# JPA Entity inheritance

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Presume I have this class:

```
@Entity
public class VehicleReport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(ORDINAL)
    private VehicleType vehicleType;

    @OneToMany?
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles;
}
```

And I would like each vehicle type to have it's own subtable, with needed information about each vehicle type.
For instance:

Abstract class is `Vehicle`:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Vehicle {
    @ManyToOne
    public VehicleReport report;

}
```

And concrete class for each vehicle type

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    //Specific "Car" columns
}
```

How do i make the join in the parent class `VehicleReport` to fetch the correct children dependent on `VehicleType` in `VehicleReport`?

I've read about `@DiscriminatorColumn`, but that would mean I would save `VehicleType` in all of my child tables as well? Even though they have an FK pointing to the parent `VehicleReport`?

All help appriciaated

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.
First you need to `@Inheritance` annotation for `Vehicle` class.

Then define a `@DiscriminatorColumn` to `Vehicle` class

define a `@DiscriminatorValue` to `Car` class. Like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISC", discriminatorType=STRING, length=20)
@DiscriminatorValue("DISC_VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {
    @ManyToOne
    public VehicleReport report;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DISC_CAR")
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    //Specific "Car" columns
}
```

The `@Discriminator...` annotations can be used when the inheritance strategy is `strategy=SINGLE_TABLE` and you would like to specify the columns related to inheritance. These annotations are doesn't make a sense when the inheritance strategy is `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`. But only with `@Inheritance`, your code should work also as [@Veselin Davidow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872384/)'s answer. Because the default strategy is `strategy=SINGLE_TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this means I would need an extra column per table, thats called `DISC` right?

Comment: @RobinJonsson No you don't need to crate the column. It will be created automically. The `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` annotations are just provides you to customize the column name and values. These are taking default values if you don't define the annotations

Comment: @RobinJonsson And discriminator annotations are needed only when your inheritance is `@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)` and you would like to specify the columns related to inheritance. The aren't discriminator columns when your inheritance is `@Inheritance(strategy=TABLE_PER_CLASS)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the entities using inheritance strategy

```
   @Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
   public abstract class Vehicle {
        @ManyToOne
        public VehicleReport report;

   }

  @Entity
  public class Car extends Vehicle {
    //Specific "Car" columns
  }
```

And in the report class

```
@OneToMany
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles;
```

will work as expected - collection of vehicles each being of different class. You can even do a "select all vehicle" (without coming from the relationship) and  it should work properly.

You can check a nice blog [here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/)  and some more information [here](https://xebia.com/blog/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping-inheritance-hierarchies/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I specify the collection of vehicles to also persist themselfs when i save the parent object, they will be saved in the correct table dependent on what instance they are of?

Comment: yes if you have like vehicle repository or something it should save to corresponding table. Check the first blog post that I linked. It has very nice explanation of the inheritance strategies